# How to filter a nested array in React TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, nested, mantine

So, I have this filter already working that implements a List in React (Using Mantine.dev as my CSS template):

```
<List>
  {locations.filter(location => {
    const locServices: Service[] = [];
    location.services.forEach(service => {
      if (service.locationPerformsService) {
        locServices.push(service);
      }
    });
    return query === ''
      ? location
      : location.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) && location;
  }).map((location, index) => (

    <UnstyledButton
      key={index}
      className={
        selectedLocation.risCode === location.risCode
          ? 'selected-location-navbar-item location-navbar-item'
          : 'location-navbar-item'
      }
    >

    </UnstyledButton>
  ))}
</List>
```

I do have a nested array that I need to verify, but I can't see a better way to implement both together:

```
  locations.forEach(location => {
    const locServices: Service[] = [];
    location.services.forEach(service => {
      if (service.locationPerformsService) {
        console.log(locServices);
        locServices.push(service);
      }
    });
    if (locServices.length > 0) {
      console.log(location.name);
      console.log(locServices);
    }
  });
```

Can you guys give me a hint or show me how to continue ?

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can we use `filter`  istead of `for each` ?

```
locations.forEach(location => {
    const locServices = location.services.filter(service => service.locationPerformsService);
    if (locServices.length > 0) {
      console.log(location.name);
      console.log(locServices);
    }
  });
```

Comment: That actually doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to read two arrays, right? So you can use the logic to aggregate, like sets, the same idea from Aman Sandhwani.

```js
arr1 = [{}]
arr2 = [{}]
for(i=0; i<len(arr1); i++) {
    for(j=0; j<len(arr2); j++) {
        if arr1[i].location == arr2.service.location {
            // todo your action
        }
    }
}
```

Note: approach from Aman is the same idea but simplified.

Answer (score 0):

The array was right, the issue was with the filter, so I had to change the ternary operator to an old if/else/if to do more verifications and added the second array.

```
      {locations.filter(location => {
        const locServices: Service[] = [];
        location.services.forEach(service => {
          if (service.locationPerformsService) {
            locServices.push(service);
          }
        });
        if (query === '') {
          return location;
        }
        else if(location.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))
        {
          return location;
        }
        else if(locServices.length > 0)
        { 
          return locServices;
        }
      }).map((location, index) => (
        <UnstyledButton
          key={index}
          className={
            selectedLocation.risCode === location.risCode
              ? 'selected-location-navbar-item location-navbar-item'
              : 'location-navbar-item'
          }
        >
```